# I tried to connect the mongodb container to mongo-express UI but not able to create the database and getting could not create collection error

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongo-express

[image: The command i used to run the mongo-express container]

After that I'm not able to add new database and getting this error:

[image: Error in MOngo-express while creating new databse]

Meanwhile, when I checked the logs I'm getting some Authentication failed error

[image: Error in Logs]